# Go AES CFB compatibility

Tags: go, cryptography, aes

I am developing a client-side app in Go that relies on AES CFB.  The server-side is written in C.  My problem is that Go's AES CFB implementation appears to differ from many others (including OpenSSL).  I wrote this to test my theory:-

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/hex"
  "crypto/cipher"
  "crypto/aes"
)

func encrypt_aes_cfb(plain, key, iv []byte) (encrypted []byte) {
  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  encrypted = make([]byte, len(plain))
  stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
  stream.XORKeyStream(encrypted, plain)
  return
}

func decrypt_aes_cfb(encrypted, key, iv []byte) (plain []byte) {
  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  plain = make([]byte, len(encrypted))
  stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
  stream.XORKeyStream(plain, encrypted)
  return
}

func main() {
  plain := []byte("Hello world.....")
  key := []byte("01234567890123456789012345678901")
  iv := []byte("0123456789012345")
  enc := encrypt_aes_cfb(plain, key, iv)
  dec := decrypt_aes_cfb(enc, key, iv)
  fmt.Println("Key: ", hex.EncodeToString(key))
  fmt.Println("IV:  ", hex.EncodeToString(iv))
  fmt.Println("Enc: ", hex.EncodeToString(enc))
  fmt.Println("In:  ", hex.EncodeToString(plain))
  fmt.Println("Out: ", hex.EncodeToString(dec))
}
```

When this is run, it appears to work perfectly, however, if the encrypted bytes are pasted into another AES implementation and decrypted using the same key and IV, the plaintext is corrupted (except for the first Byte).  http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ provides a simple means to test this.  Any suggestions why this might be happening and how I can resolve it?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Hi ,Is this problem resolved? I meet same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this with the following inputs because I was unsure of the bit/byte order for both inputs and outputs :

```
Key:  00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:   00000000000000000000000000000000
Enc:  66
In:   00
Out:  00
```

http://play.golang.org/p/wl2y1EE6lK

Which matches the tool you provided, and then this :

```
Key:  00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:   00000000000000000000000000000000
Enc:  66e94b
In:   000000
Out:  000000
```

http://play.golang.org/p/DNC42m2oU5

Which **doesn't** match the tool :

```
6616f9
```

http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/63687gDNzymApefh/

The first byte matches, which indicates there may be a feedback issue.

So I checked the Go package's code <strike>and I think there is a bug [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/cipher/cfb.go#L34) :</strike>

```
func (x *cfb) XORKeyStream(dst, src []byte) {
    for len(src) > 0 {
        if x.outUsed == len(x.out) {
            x.b.Encrypt(x.out, x.next)
            x.outUsed = 0
        }

        if x.decrypt {
            // We can precompute a larger segment of the
            // keystream on decryption. This will allow
            // larger batches for xor, and we should be
            // able to match CTR/OFB performance.
            copy(x.next[x.outUsed:], src)
        }
        n := xorBytes(dst, src, x.out[x.outUsed:])
        if !x.decrypt {
            copy(x.next[x.outUsed:], dst) // BUG? `dst` should be `src`
        }
        dst = dst[n:]
        src = src[n:]
        x.outUsed += n
    }
}
```

### EDIT

After a second look at CFB mode it seems that Go's code is fine, so yeah it may be the other implementations are wrong.

Comment: Interesting...  There aren't any test vectors in [the tests](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/cipher/cfb_test.go) either...

Comment: Another possibility is that Go is good and the AES URL is broken. I've discovered a bug on the server-side I was testing against so I've built a case on weak foundations.

Comment: Yeah, actually after a second look at CFB it seems it should be feeding back from `dst` and actually Go's code looks pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

(Firstly, an obligatory warning: CFB mode is a sign of homegrown crypto. Unless you're implementing OpenPGP you should be using an AE mode like AES-GCM or NaCl's secretbox. If you're forced to use CFB mode, I hope that you're authenticating ciphertexts with an HMAC at least.)

With that aside, CFB mode in Go is there for OpenPGP support. (OpenPGP uses both a tweaked CFB mode called OCFB, *and* standard CFB mode in different places.) The Go OpenPGP code appears to interoperate with other implementations at least.

Nick is correct that test vectors are missing in the Go `crypto` package. The testing was coming from the OpenPGP code, but packages should stand alone and so I'll add tests to `crypto/cipher` with the test vectors from section F.3.13 of [1].

My best guess for the source of any differences is that CFB is parameterised by a chunk size. This is generally a power of two number of bits up to the block size of the underlying cipher. If the chunk size isn't specified then it's generally taken to be the cipher block size, which is what the Go code does. See [1], section 6.3. A more friendly explanation is given by [2].

Small chunk sizes were used in the dark ages (the late 90s) when people worried about things like cipher resync in the face of ciphertext loss. If another implementation is using CFB1 or CFB8 then it'll be very different from Go's CFB mode and many others. (Go's code does not support smaller chunk sizes.)

[1] http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm actually on the verge of abandoning this project.  In an effort to learn Go, I implemented the original Mixmaster specification (which uses 3DES CBC).  That went fine but the new Mix spec, with support for large RSA keys, uses AES_CFB in addition to 3DES.  It's probably gone beyond a sensible learning exercise now and I should let it go and move on!